# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi aplicación de hasta el inicio?

Tags: android-studio

Estoy creando una aplicación conecte varios layout con el `activity main` con una pequeña lista (no utilice el `listView`) el detalle es que, para acceder a las demás tengo que pasar por el primero y yo quiero que desde que se ejecute la aplicación me deje acceder a las demás independiente de cual sea y que al regresar no me muestre los layout que se abren.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtServicios);
      txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), service.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);


            TextView Contactame = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtContactame);
            Contactame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent in = new Intent(v.getContext(), Contac.class);
                    startActivityForResult(in, 0);


                    TextView Privacidad = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPrivacidad);
                    Privacidad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent in = new Intent(v.getContext(), Priv.class);
                            startActivityForResult(in, 0);


                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        }
     });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando `startActivityForResult` es porque estas esperando un resultado de tu segunda actividad, si solo quieres ir a esa actividad podrias usar `startActivity(i)`.

Para no volver a los activities que has ido anteriormente debes asegurarte elimnarlos de memoria con el metodo `finish()`

usando `finish` al presionar el boton de ir atras:

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
    }
```

Comment: ok,lo probare y te comento, y gracias por tu apoyo